# Calculate double integral, limits

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm working on the following problem:

> Calculate $$ \iint_D x^2 y^4 dx dy$$ where $D$ is $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :x^4 < y < x^{1/8} \}$.

I'm familiar with how to solve double integrals, however I need help with how to come up with the upper and lower limits for the integrals. What confuses me is that there is only one interval with both x and y in it.

Comment: Have you drawn the region?

Comment: Hint: for what values of $x$ does $x^4<x^{1/8}$ hold?

Comment: And first: for what values of $x$
 is $x^{1/8}$ defined?

Comment: $y$ is between $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=x^{1/8}$. Where the graphs meet? Using the points of intersection, you can determine where $f<g$.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^{4}}^{x^{\frac{1}{8}}}x^{2} y^{4}\ d yd x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2} \left(x^{\frac{5}{8}}-x^{20}\right)}{5}d x=\frac{31}{667}$$

Answer (score -2):

If you plot the graphs, $ y = x^4 $ and $ y = x^{1/8} $, it will be fairly clear what the region you are integrating over is, and it is also fairly simple to verify that any point in that region satisfies the inequality $ x^4 \lt y \lt x^{1/8} $.

To represent the region in the bounds of the integral, since we are integrating with dx first then dy, we would get $ y = x^{1/8} $ or $ x = y^8 $ as the upper bound, and similarly $ x = y^{1/4} $ as the lower bound.
So we would get $$ \int_{0}^1\int_{y^{1/4}}^{y^8}x^2y^4dxdy $$

Hope this helps.